# Unable to get runtime type of a variable in Scala

Tags: scala, types, runtime

I try to get the runtime-type of a variable (NOT the type of the reference), i.e. the output i get in the Scala console:

```
scala> val data = Seq(1,2,3)
data: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

What I'm interested in here is that the default implementation of `Seq` is a `List`.

How can I get this information in a normal Scala application?

I tried:

```
val data =  Seq(1,2,3)
println(data.getClass)
```

but this gives

```
class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Edit: It seems that I misinterpreted the output of the scala console. `List` is not the runtime type but the exact compile-time type. The type of the reference is `Seq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives correct answer, as far as :: is a class, which is used as implementation

```
sealed abstract class List[+A]() extends scala.collection.AbstractSeq[A] with scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq[A]

final case class ::[B](private val hd : B, private[scala] val tl : scala.collection.immutable.List[B]) extends scala.collection.immutable.List[B]
```

Comment: I still don't see why the scala console says `List` and not `::`?

Comment: Seq(...) returns a `List`, the console is referring to the compile-time type.  When you use getClass you get the exact runtime type.  `::` is a subtype of `List`.  `List` is infact abstract so you will never get a `List` as a runtime type, it will always be a `::` or a `Nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Sergey has mentioned above, `Cons` is a subclass of `List`

```scala
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

The `$colon$colon` is just the toString of `::`

Say, if I create a function called

```
def :: ="hello"
```

the compiler would just convert this to be

```java
 public String $colon$colon(){
    return "hello";
  }
```

[image]

References : 
1. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1
2. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html